# Chrome adding additional characters to PHP AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Chrome shows additional chars at the beginning and ending of the response because of that I cant use if statements such as

```
if(result=="Saved"){
   alert("Yihuu");
}
```

With firefox I dont have any problems.

How can I prevent this issue?

**JavaScript Code**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/RestHmdy/api.php/register",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            success: function (result) {

               alert(result);

            },

            error: function (xhr, status, err) {

                 alert("Error "+err,xhr,status);

             }

     })
```

PHP Response Code

```
if($stmt->execute()){

                    echo "Saved";

                }else{

                    echo "Unsaved";                 
                }
```

[Firefoxs Pure Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFzLH.png)

[Chrome Broken Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibiZP.png)

Comment: `if (result.trim() == "Saved" ){...` or even better, fix your serverside code so it doesn't send additional characters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "trim" solved my problem